# Firing a trigger on update of all columns expect 3 specified ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table with columns lets say: col1, col2, col3 ... col20.
I want to create a trigger on that table, that will be fired on update of any of that table columns, expect col1, col2 and col3, without having to list all the others. So that trigger will NOT be fired if: ONLY col1, col2 and col3 are updated or only one of them or only two of them. Just like i would start trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE OF col4, col5, col6 ... col20
ON MY_TABLE
```

But the problem is that my table have 269 columns, and i don't want to list them, even if i try im getting error "ORA-04086: trigger description too long, move comments into triggering code". Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on having more that 256 columns in a table; Oracle does not recommend it.  Believe me, you are in a nightmare situation with respect to fragmentation.  There are other ways around such a bad design (e.g. view bringing 2 multi-column [<256] tables together).

Comment: Thanks for your reply:). That database isn't my, i can't mess with the table structure.

Comment: @Anici forewarned is the keyword here.  Make sure the app owners know of this BAD design and the implications of it.  It won't scale, and trouble is around the corner if not already hitting.